# maintain rounded corner when resizing div

Tags: css, border-radius

I have a layout with a div which has rounded corners filling the whole screen (to get the look and feel of some member or credit card). So in a simplified way it's just

```css
.card {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
</div>
```

But when reducing the browser size the corners become to big obviously. If I use percent for the border roundness they get distorted. Is there any way to maintain the ratio between div and border-radius without a ton of Javascript?

Comment: go bigger in the radius, 999px or 100vmax

Comment: As per your css border-radius: 45vw; will help you

Comment: Thanks, but both answers have the same effect. they give me a semicircle on both sides (or on both ends depending on resolutions). I'd need a roundness that reminds of a credit card. So I need straight edges on all 4 sides. Using about 2-3 vh or vw seems more promising, bur still changes the roundness to much with resizing (especially in portait)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **vmax** unit for the border radius which better suits the situation when the viewport/window orientation/format can both be portrait or landscape (see example in snippet below, adjust the value as needed).

Here's the description from mdn web docs

> *vmax* represents in percentage the largest of vw and vh.
>
> For small, large, and dynamic viewport sizes, the respective
> viewport-percentage units are svmax, lvmax, and dvmax. vmax represents
> the viewport-percentage length unit based on the browser default
> viewport size.

(from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

```css
.card {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3vmax;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aspect-ratio property which I rarely use for maintaining ratio around the boxes but I don't think this is suitable for every browser just go through the browser specs and if your browser supports then give it a try or you can set the aspect ratio of any box properly by adjusting the padding for  'before' pseudo class.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) to draw perfectly matched rounded corners on your box.